# Do both these ellipses satisfy the same conditions?

Tags: conic-sections

I was solving a problem that asked for the equation of the ellipse with the following properties: vertex at $(-10,5)$, focus at $(-2,5)$, eccentricity $\frac{1}{2}$. I think I found *two* such ellipses, but since the book only lists one. I want to make sure I'm not mistaken.

[image: ellipse]

The larger, which the book lists, is
$$\frac{(x-6)^2}{256}+\frac{(y-5)^2}{192}=1$$
and the smaller is
$$\frac{(x+\frac{14}{3})^2}{256/9}+\frac{(y-5)^2}{192/9}=1$$

Both have $(-10,5)$ as their leftmost vertex, and the large ellipse has $(-2,5)$ as it's leftmost focus. As far as I can tell, the smaller is a scaled-down version of the larger, preserving eccentricity $\frac{1}{2}$, with $(-2,5)$ as its rightmost focus. Does that all check out?

Comment: Have not checked arithmetic, but it seems clear there are two such ellipses, since given the vertex, the focus supplied can be either the near focus or the far focus.

Comment: That would make sense.